# Best way to implement sort asc or desc in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sorting

Is there an elegant way to implement a sort asc and desc actions in the views/controller in rails?

What I have is the common index.html.erb view that lists all of my data of certain model and I want to add some small buttons (or make the title clickable) to sort the list ascending or descending of that column. I am wondering if there is an elegant and efficient way to do it or should I just add a new controller for every column (or button) I want this action to happen.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Here are two examples that I'm using. The first one with `@plans` is where I just want to order a decimal from lowest to highest. The other example is a bit more complicated where I want to order user files from newest to oldest. I then used a second variable to group the files by the date created. Both examples where performed in the controllers.

```
@plans = Plan.order("price")

@files= @user.files.order("id DESC").all
@dates = @files.group_by { |t| t.created_at }
```

For clickable buttons in your view, check out Ryan Bates's Railscast episode covering this information.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns

Comment: Should this code be implemented in the view, controller or helper?

Comment: Doing `@user.files.order(id: :desc)`  is the most elegant way to do it if you are static typing. 
If its dynamic is way better to just do `@user.files.order("#{criteria} #{direction}")`

Comment: @kobaltz : great answer, helped me :)

Answer (score 3):

I recently used a gem called `sorted` with good results in case you want to use a pre-packaged solution for this instead of rolling out your own.

https://github.com/mynameisrufus/sorted

Answer (score -1):

here is relation of data that shows you how we access name in acceding order

```
@results = Result.has_pro.ascending(:name).page(params[:page])
```