# How to order by descending value in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

I am trying to show the list of jobs ordered by `median_salary` by descending order. So far, it seems to only take into account the first number of `median_salary`. So something like 900 is listed above 1000, even though the value of 1000 > 900.

homes_controller.rb:

```
def index
  nyc_highest = Highestpaidjob.where("city = ?", "NYC")
  @nyc_highest = nyc_highest.order("median_salary DESC")
end
```

index.html.erb:

`<%= @nyc_highest.inspect %>`

returns:

`#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Highestpaidjob id: 11, job: "Architect, City Planner", median_salary: "95928.48", count: 237, margin_of_error: "", city: "NYC", state: "New York", created_at: "2016-07-25 18:17:17", updated_at: "2016-07-25 18:17:17">, #<Highestpaidjob id: 7, job: "Medical", median_salary: "170507.69", count: 128, margin_of_error: "", city: "NYC", state: "New York", created_at: "2016-07-25 18:09:30", updated_at: "2016-07-25 18:09:30">]>`

It is listing 95928.48 as higher than 170507.69. Am I missing a condition?

I've looked at [Best way to implement sort asc or desc in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857888/best-way-to-implement-sort-asc-or-desc-in-rails) and it seemed to suggest the way I am currently writing the sort.

Comment: Your median_salary field is a string, that is why you're having this problem. You need to change your type of string into int either by a migration or by `to_i` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your `median_salary` database field is string and it's sorted as string. You need to cast it to integer in order clause, or create a migration, which will change field datatype.

Difference between strings being sorting and floats being sorted:

```
irb(main):001:0> ["95928.48", "170507.69"].sort
=> ["170507.69", "95928.48"]
irb(main):002:0> [95928.48, 170507.69].sort
=> [95928.48, 170507.69]
```

In postgres your order clause should looks like this:

```
@nyc_highest = nyc_highest.order("CAST(median_salary as FLOAT) DESC")
```

Comment: This worked for me. I wanted to be able to display the `median_salary` with the comma in place (i.e. 12,000) but it did not end up working. I have created migration to change `median_salary` type to float instead. But the code above to cast to float did work as well.

Comment: Did you try [number_to_currency](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_currency) helper?

Answer (score 1):

As @teksisto said, you should change the `median_salary` for float or some type that accepts decimals. Also, I would suggest to create a scope on your model, something like

```
scope :nyc_highest, -> { where("city = ?", "NYC").order("median_salary DESC") }
```

on your `Highestpaidjob` model. Then, you just call `Highestpaidjob.nyc_highest` in any place of your application you like.

For changing the `median_salary` data type:

```
rails g migration ChangeMedianSalaryType
```

then edit your migration file:

```
class ChangeMedianSalaryType < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column :highestpaidjobs, :median_salary, :float
  end

  def down
    change_column :highestpaidjobs, :median_slary, :string
  end
end
```